# When smtp mail returns a "password not accepted from server"

Tags: authentication, passwords, phpmailer

You get this error from phpmailer.

> "Password not accepted from server: 535 Incorrect authentication data"

What causes this?

Answer (score 1):

You must make sure that the `Username` given for the log-on is the same as the `SetFrom` email address.

This will return an error:

```
$mail->Username   = "myemailaddress@gmail.com";      // GMAIL username 
$mail->Password   = "password";                      // GMAIL password 
$mail->SetFrom('mysetfromaddress@gmail.com', 'Pagelinks');
```

This should not.

```
$mail->Username   = "mysetfromaddress@gmail.com";    // GMAIL username 
$mail->Password   = "password";                      // GMAIL password 
$mail->SetFrom('mysetfromaddress@gmail.com', 'Pagelinks');
```

When the `Username` and `SetFrom` do not match the authentication fails (according to an article found on Google).